# Baseball Statistics Through a Form

Tags: html, css, ruby

I am trying to make an application for compiling baseball statistics. I would like to be able to enter information about an at-bat and receive statistics. 
I would like to be able to show the amount of times singles double triple home run and divide that by the amount of times the at-bat form has been answered. Basically, I want to show Batting Average by doing `(single+double+triple+homerun)/(atbats-walks)`. I would also like to show `groundball/(at-bats-walks)`, `flyball/(atbats-walks)`, and `(((1*single)+(2*double)+(3*triple)+(4*homerun))/(atbats))`, etc. I only know Ruby, HTML, and CSS.

Here is my at-bat form page

```
<style>
   h1 {
    color: white;
  }
  .moveloco {
    text-align:center;;
    color:white;
  }
  .moveloco2 {
    text-align:center;
  }
  .centit {
    text-align:center;
  }
</style>
<h1 class= "moveloco">Input Statistics: Location 1</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <br  />
        <br  />
        <div style="background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" class="jumbotron">  
        <h3>What was the Pitch Type?</h3>
        <br  />
        <h3>Where did the Ball Go?</h3>
        <br  />
        <select input id="end_ball_location" name="ebloco">
          <option value='lout'>Left Field</option>
          <option value='cout'>Center Field</option>
          <option value='rout'>Right Field</option>
          <option value='lin'>Left Side of the Infield</option>
          <option value='min'>Middle of the Infield </option>
          <option value='rin'>Right Side of the Infield</option>
        </select>   
        <br  />
        <br  />
        <br  />
        <br  />
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <br  />
      <br  />
      <br  />
      <br  />
      <br  />
      <img src = "http://i62.tinypic.com/2gt51dc.png" alt="field" height="350" width="400">
      <br  />
    </div>
    <br  />
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <br  />
      <div style="background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" class="jumbotron">
        <div class='moveloco2'>
          <h3>What Type of Hit was It?</h3>
        </div>
        <br  />
        <div class='moveloco2'>
        <select id="hit_type" name="hit_type">
          <option value='gball'>Groundball</option>
          <option value='ld'>Line Drive</option>
          <option value='flyball'>Fly Ball</option>
        </select>
        <br  />
        <br  />
        </div>
        <div class='moveloco2'>
        <h3>What was the At Bat Result?</h3>
        <br  />
        <div class='moveloco2'>
          <select id="at_bat_result" name="at_bat_result">
            <option value='single'>Single</option>
            <option value='double'>Double</option>
            <option value='triple'>Triple</option>
            <option value='homerun'>Home Run</option>
            <option value='out'>Out</option>
            <option value='walk'>Walk</option>
          </select> 
          <br  />
          <br  />
          <br  />
        </div>
        <div class='moveloco2'>
          <input type='submit'>
        </div>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

application controller
I don't know what to put.

statistics show page

```
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;

}
.pwsth, .container {
  text-align:center;
}
  .tfass {
    text-align:center;
      color:white;
  }
  .pagination {

  }
</style>
<br  />
<div class="tfass">
  <h1 class="text-center">Batting Statistics</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <br  />
      <br  />
      <br  />
      <br  />
      <img src = "http://i59.tinypic.com/nvbay1.png" alt="field" height="300" width="300">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <br  />
      <br  />
      <br  />
      <br  />
      <img src = "http://i62.tinypic.com/2gt51dc.png" alt="field" height="350" width="400">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div style="background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" class="jumbotron">
          <div class="asd">
            <h3 class="text-center">Pitch Location 1</h3>
            <br  />
            <table style="width:100%">
              <tr>
                <th class= "pwsth">BA</th>
                <th class= "pwsth">SLG</th>
                <th class= "pwsth">OPS</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="pwsth">stat</td>
                <td class="pwsth">stat</td>
                <td class="pwsth">stat</td> 
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class= "pwsth">GB %</th>
                <th class= "pwsth">FB %</th>
                <th class= "pwsth">LD %</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="pwsth">stat</td>
                <td class="pwsth">stat</td>
                <td class="pwsth">stat</td> 
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class= "pwsth">idk</th>
                <th class= "pwsth">idk</th>
                <th class= "pwsth">RC</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="pwsth">idk</td>
                <td class="pwsth">idk</td>
                <td class="pwsth">stat</td> 
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <nav class = "nacent">
            <ul class="pagination">
              <li><a href="advstat/1">1</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/2">2</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/3">3</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/4">4</a></li>

              <div></div><li><a href="advstat/5">5</a></li>
              <div></div>
              <li><a href="advstat/6">6</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/7">7</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/8">8</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/9">9</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/10">10</a></li>
              <div></div>
              <li><a href="advstat/11">11</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/12">12</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/13">13</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/14">14</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/15">15</a></li>
              <div></div>
              <li><a href="advstat/16">16</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/17">17</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/18">18</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/19">19</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/20">20</a></li>
              <div></div>
              <li><a href="advstat/21">21</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/22">22</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/23">23</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/24">24</a></li>
              <li><a href="advstat/25">25</a></li>
              <li>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay. Do you have a question?

Comment: @Jordan pretty much how do I calculate the statistics?

Comment: You'd have to use Javascript or something similar to actually calculate your values. You already have the calculations you need, you would just need to turn them into functions.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry I have no idea how to use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use JavaScript or something similar if trying to calculate it client-side. If you don't know JavaScript here's a good start:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp